# Azure Web Static Apps can't read .env with NEXT_PUBLIC prefix

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, next.js, azure-static-web-app

let say I have .env like this

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_PATH = value1
```

this .env is working as expected in my local, but after I deployed to Azure Web Static Apps and also added this .env in configuration[image]

my application seems can't read this .env as I debug it through console it returns the value of `undefined`. [image]

I already know the mitigation by adding the value through my `.yml` file and `next.config.js`, but as I know this solutions is not really good to be implemented in real production scenarion. Is there any answer for this issue yet?

Comment: according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings    you can't read app setting in front end unless it is to build the app so the work around would be that you can  use an azure httptrigged function which will provide all the etings you want just make a get request form the next.js app

Comment: How you are reading the value?

Comment: I already put the answer below @Harshitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a mitigation I was putting my PUBLIC_ENV inside my .yml file and I put the value on Github Secrets.